# Mahout: adjusted cosine similarity for item based recommender

Tags: java, mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender, cosine-similarity

For an assignment I'm supposed to test different types of recommenders, which I have to implement first. I've been looking around for a good library to do that (I had thought about Weka at first) and stumbled upon Mahout.

I must therefore put forward that: a) I'm completely new to Mahout b) I do not have a strong background in recommenders nor their algorithms (otherwise I wouldn't be doing this class...) and c) sorry but I'm far from being the best developper in the world ==> I'd appreciate if you could use layman terms (as far as possible...) :)

I've been following some tutorials (e.g. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yD40rVKUwPI), as well as [part2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63k560Livmg)) and got some preliminary results on item-based and user-based recommenders.

However, I'm not very happy with the item-based prediction. So far, I've only found similarity functions that do not **take into consideration the users' rating-biases**. I was wondering if there is something like `adjusted cosine similarity`. Any hints?

Comment: you can try to extends the AbstractSimilarity class an implement one yourself

Comment: ok thanks I'll have a look into that. I'm pretty surprised I can't seem to find anything about that (other people asking the same questions, ready-to-use implementations, ...)

Comment: I found this class, which is now deprecated. Do you know if there is any way of finding what I should use instead? (I'm using mahout-0.9 and I think this was removed!) http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/mahout-0.8-cdh5.0.0/mahout-core/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/recommender/BiasedItemBasedRecommender.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of the `AdjustedCosineSimilarity` I created. You must remember that this will be slower than `PearsonCorrelationSimilarity` because of the sqrt computations, but will produce better results. At least for my dataset results were much better. But you should make a trade off, quality/performance, and depending of your needs you should use the implementation you want.

```
/**
 * Custom implementation of {@link AdjustedCosineSimilarity}
 * 
 * @author dmilchevski
 *
 */
public class AdjustedCosineSimilarity extends AbstractSimilarity {

  /**
   * Creates new {@link AdjustedCosineSimilarity}
   * 
   * @param dataModel
   * @throws TasteException
   */
    public AdjustedCosineSimilarity(DataModel dataModel)
            throws TasteException {
        this(dataModel, Weighting.UNWEIGHTED);
    }

    /**
     * Creates new {@link AdjustedCosineSimilarity}
     * 
     * @param dataModel
     * @param weighting
     * @throws TasteException
     */
    public AdjustedCosineSimilarity(DataModel dataModel, Weighting weighting)
            throws TasteException {
        super(dataModel, weighting, true);
        Preconditions.checkArgument(dataModel.hasPreferenceValues(),
                "DataModel doesn't have preference values");
    }

    /**
     * Compute the result
     */
    @Override
    double computeResult(int n, double sumXY, double sumX2, double sumY2, double sumXYdiff2) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return Double.NaN;
        }
        // Note that sum of X and sum of Y don't appear here since they are
        // assumed to be 0;
        // the data is assumed to be centered.
        double denominator = Math.sqrt(sumX2) * Math.sqrt(sumY2);
        if (denominator == 0.0) {
            // One or both parties has -all- the same ratings;
            // can't really say much similarity under this measure
            return Double.NaN;
        }
        return sumXY / denominator;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the average preference
     * @param prefs
     * @return
     */
    private double averagePreference(PreferenceArray prefs){
        double sum = 0.0;
        int n = prefs.length();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            sum+=prefs.getValue(i);
        }
        if(n>0){
            return sum/n;
        }
        return 0.0d;
    }

    /**
     * Compute the item similarity between two items
     */
    @Override
    public double itemSimilarity(long itemID1, long itemID2) throws TasteException {
        DataModel dataModel = getDataModel();
        PreferenceArray xPrefs = dataModel.getPreferencesForItem(itemID1);
        PreferenceArray yPrefs = dataModel.getPreferencesForItem(itemID2);
        int xLength = xPrefs.length();
        int yLength = yPrefs.length();

        if (xLength == 0 || yLength == 0) {
            return Double.NaN;
        }

        long xIndex = xPrefs.getUserID(0);
        long yIndex = yPrefs.getUserID(0);
        int xPrefIndex = 0;
        int yPrefIndex = 0;

        double sumX = 0.0;
        double sumX2 = 0.0;
        double sumY = 0.0;
        double sumY2 = 0.0;
        double sumXY = 0.0;
        double sumXYdiff2 = 0.0;
        int count = 0;

        // No, pref inferrers and transforms don't appy here. I think.

        while (true) {
            int compare = xIndex < yIndex ? -1 : xIndex > yIndex ? 1 : 0;
            if (compare == 0) {
                // Both users expressed a preference for the item
                double x = xPrefs.getValue(xPrefIndex);
                double y = yPrefs.getValue(yPrefIndex);
                long xUserId = xPrefs.getUserID(xPrefIndex);
                long yUserId = yPrefs.getUserID(yPrefIndex);

                double xMean = averagePreference(dataModel.getPreferencesFromUser(xUserId));
                double yMean = averagePreference(dataModel.getPreferencesFromUser(yUserId));

                sumXY += (x - xMean) * (y - yMean);
                sumX += x;
                sumX2 += (x - xMean) * (x - xMean);
                sumY += y;
                sumY2 += (y - yMean) * (y - yMean);
                double diff = x - y;
                sumXYdiff2 += diff * diff;
                count++;
            }
            if (compare <= 0) {
                if (++xPrefIndex == xLength) {
                    break;
                }
                xIndex = xPrefs.getUserID(xPrefIndex);
            }
            if (compare >= 0) {
                if (++yPrefIndex == yLength) {
                    break;
                }
                yIndex = yPrefs.getUserID(yPrefIndex);
            }
        }

        double result;

        // See comments above on these computations
        double n = (double) count;
        double meanX = sumX / n;
        double meanY = sumY / n;
        // double centeredSumXY = sumXY - meanY * sumX - meanX * sumY + n *
        // meanX * meanY;
        double centeredSumXY = sumXY - meanY * sumX;
        // double centeredSumX2 = sumX2 - 2.0 * meanX * sumX + n * meanX *
        // meanX;
        double centeredSumX2 = sumX2 - meanX * sumX;
        // double centeredSumY2 = sumY2 - 2.0 * meanY * sumY + n * meanY *
        // meanY;
        double centeredSumY2 = sumY2 - meanY * sumY;
//      result = computeResult(count, centeredSumXY, centeredSumX2,
//              centeredSumY2, sumXYdiff2);

        result = computeResult(count, sumXY, sumX2, sumY2, sumXYdiff2);

        if (!Double.isNaN(result)) {
            result = normalizeWeightResult(result, count,
                    dataModel.getNumUsers());
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll try to check it in the next days!